# How much are overridden Machines buffed?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

I recently overrode a Watcher, because I thought it would be funny. Another Watcher came up and kicked him a few times, while I shook my head in disappointment, thinking my Watcher would die in less time than it took for me to override it. However, my Watcher stood up and headbutted the other Watcher and instantly killed it.

Obviously, my overridden Watcher received some buffs for it to be able to do this, but how *much* are overridden Machines buffed? Is it just damage or is their health increased also?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Overridden machines deal out double the damage and take half the damage compared to a normal machine.

[Source](https://horizonzerodawn.fandom.com/wiki/Override):

> Overridden machines gain a 100% boost to their damage dealt while
>   taking 50% less damage. This means that in a one-on-one fight between
>   the same machines, the overridden machine has a greater advantage.